# How to restrict other columns data getting updated while updating specific columns of a table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

How to restrict only those columns which I would want to update in a database table rather than updating all the columns of a table?

The following is to update only remarks column

```
@Test
    public void updateProject() {
        try {
            Project project = new Project();
            project.setProjectId(234L);
            project.setRemarks("from junit");
            projectService.update(project);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I execute the above it updated all the other column in table, consequently this makes all other column values as null.

How can I resolve this issue?

**DAOImpl code**

```
@Override
    public void update(project project) {    
        entityManager.merge(project);
        entityManager.flush();      
    }
```

**Update 1** Modified code

```
@Test
    public void updateProject() {
        try {
            Project project = new Project();
            project = projectService.load(234L);            
            project.setRemarks("from junit");
            projectService.update(project);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're merging a new object with all `null` fields except `remarks` with an object already persistent in the db. That's not the right way: from the `Hibernate` reference manual:

> A straightforward way to update the state of an entity instance is to
>   find() it, and then manipulate it directly, while the persistence
>   context is open: [Modifying persistent objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1312)

If you need to modify a persistent object, first you have to load it, then you edit only the fields you need to update and then you save it.

So, you could just load the `Project` entity from the DB and update only the fields you need and then `save()` it.
The `save()` actually isn't necessary as `Hibernate` checks that the object is modified and automatically saves it.

```
@Test
    public void updateProject() {
        try {
            // Load the project entity from the DB using it's id 234L
            project.setRemarks("from junit");
            projectService.save(project);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here's [how load an object](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1077).

In your `DAO` you need a  method to load the object, like for example:

```
@Override
    public Project load(Long id) {    
        return entityManager.find(Project.class, id);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I did not get your point here, could you kindly be more elaborate?

Comment: `load(Long id)` is nothing but my unique key in table. So my update statement should be `update my_table set remarks='from junit' where id=234;` So my doubt is how to load only the object? Because as you can see I am calling set method only for `remarks`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you. If `id` is your key in the table just load the object using its id. After you've loaded modify it using the set methods.

Comment: So using load method you have suggested is to load the unique id right?

Comment: @Polppan if your loading it with its *unique id* your getting a single object.

Comment: But that is what I am doing with this statement `project.setProjectId(234L);` here 234 is the id of the table.

Comment: In that way *you're not loading* the entity from the DB. You're just setting and id to a newly created object and then merging it with a persistent entity. Please see the links I've provided in my answer to see how `Hibernate` works.

Comment: Atropo Thanks a lot for insight and pointing my mistake. As suggested I have modified my code (added as Update 1) in my question and it resolved the issue. Appreciated.